# If Statements in pygame

Tags: python, loops, if-statement, pygame

Im writing a pygame Where you basically have to dodge stars. it has a store and you can buy a force field but i only want the force field to work 3 times then go away when you buy the force field `force_field = True` that works but Im having a problem with the collide part when they collide `self.force_count -=1` the problem is this will loop every fraction of a second and since the collision happens for like a second it loops three times and then you lose

Here are my If Statments:

```
    star_col = self.player_r.colliderect(self.star_r)or self.player_r.colliderect(self.star2_r)or self.player_r.colliderect(self.star3_r)

    if self.force_field == True and star_col == True:
        self.force_count+=1
        print "ship hit"
        if self.force_count == 3:
            self.force_field = False


    if star_col == True and self.force_field == False:
        self.force_field = 0
        self.state = 0
        if self.money > 0:
            self.money = self.money - 25
```

the print is just for testing but when i collide with a star it prints it 3 times then goes to the game over screen instead of just counting to one then going agian

so im wondering how i can do this with out it just adding 3 in a split second and ending

If you read through all of this thank you so much and please help me out!

-ChristianCareaga

Comment: You could limit how often the if block gets evaluated by counting how much time has passed.  Or maybe after the collision, the ship has a boolean flag for being invincible for a second or two.

Comment: interesting ill try that too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be, that you let the star disappear when it hits the ship. Maybe with a nice explosion or something :)

Otherwise you could mark a star with a bool flag as "collided" to request if you already hit this star. But this way you can only hit it once even if your ship has "left" the star and ran into it again.

Comment: thats a good idea i already have an explosion image ill try it but how can i unblit a star

Comment: if the stars are sprites, you can do use `star.kill()` on `spritecollide` , then spawn the explosion animation in a different sprite group which doesn't do sprite collisions.